# Obtaining the class with maximum frequency(python)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

so based on the following groupby code:

```
aps1.groupby(['S3bin2','S105_9bin2', 'class_predict']).size().unstack()
```

I get the following output:

```
class_predict            0      1
S3bin2 S105_9bin2                
50     50          16058.0  133.0
       100           256.0    7.0
       150           161.0    NaN
       200           160.0    1.0
       400000       4195.0   58.0
100    50           3480.0   20.0
       100            68.0    NaN
       150            43.0    1.0
       200            48.0    1.0
       400000        689.0    2.0
150    50           1617.0    6.0
       100            73.0    NaN
       150            33.0    NaN
       200            52.0    NaN
       400000        935.0    3.0
200    50           1155.0    8.0
       100            73.0    1.0
       150            37.0    NaN
       200            45.0    NaN
       400000        937.0    NaN
300000 50          11508.0  178.0
       100           748.0   11.0
       150           446.0    5.0
       200           350.0    9.0
       400000      13080.0   49.0
```

So for the group 50 in both `S3bin2` and `S105_9bin2`, the frequency of 0 is the highest. Is it possible to run a function whereby I can print the groups for which 0 has highest count, and also the count? I've tried `transform(max)` and other things but I'm not getting it.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: something like - Maximum failure (16058) at 50(S3bin2) and 50(S105_9bin2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for test maximum in all data:

First you can remove `unstack` and add [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) for `max` and [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) and last create output by `format`:

```
s = aps1.groupby(['S3bin2','S105_9bin2', 'class_predict']).size()

a = s.agg(['idxmax', 'max'])
print (a)
idxmax    (50, 50, 0)
max             16058
dtype: object

print (s.index.names)
['S3bin2', 'S105_9bin2', None]

a,b,c = a['max'], a['idxmax'], s.index.names
d = 'Maximum failure ({0}) at {1[0]}({2[0]}) and {1[1]}({2[1]})'.format(a,b,c)
print (d)
Maximum failure (16058) at 50(S3bin2) and 50(S105_9bin2)
```

---

But if want test only column `0` or `1`:

```
df = aps1.groupby(['S3bin2','S105_9bin2', 'class_predict']).size().unstack()
#change 0 to 1 for test column 1
a = df[0].agg(['idxmax', 'max'])
print (a)
idxmax    (50, 50)
max          16058
Name: 0, dtype: object

a,b,c = a['max'], a['idxmax'], df.index.names
d = 'Maximum failure ({0}) at {1[0]}({2[0]}) and {1[1]}({2[1]})'.format(a,b,c)
print (d)
Maximum failure (16058.0) at 50(S3bin2) and 50(S105_9bin2)
```

Comment: Hi jezreal, so based on your code, I tried creating the following function: def warning(data,col1,col2,target):
    s = data.groupby([col1,col2,target]).size()
    a = s.agg(['idxmax', 'max'])
    a,b,c = a['max'], a['idxmax'], data.index.names
    d = 'Maximum failure ({0}) at {1[0]}({2[0]}) and {1[1]}({2[1]})'.format(a,b,c)
    print (d)

Comment: but after running this: warning(aps1,'S3bin2','S105_9bin2','class_predict'), I get this error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: what return `print (b)` and `print (c)` ?

Comment: Return print(b) print(c) gives me the same IndexError: list out of index range

Comment: Ok, so what return `print (df.index.names)` and `s.agg(['idxmax', 'max'])` ?

Comment: I get the same error, IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: For both of them?

Comment: Yes for both..can you try to get a functional form out of it? Maybe my function is wrong somewhere

Comment: hmm, `data.groupby([col1,col2,target]).size()` working?

Comment: you mean this s = aps1.groupby(['S3bin2','S105_9bin2', 'class_predict']).size() right? It works. In fact the first answer of yours worked pretty well, its just the function where I'm getting stuck at

Comment: Waht is your pandas version?

Comment: this is the version   '0.20.3'

Comment: Sorry buddy it was a small error in my code, Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome! I was really upset ;) You can also upvote, thanks ;)

Comment: I did upvote. Anyway a small question, say if i were to obtain the maximum frequencies of 1s instead of 0s where should I tweak the code?

Comment: Sure, check edit. First solution is for test all data, second for test by columns.